# Do we have any option to copy data from clip board to MVC Jquery grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I have to copy data from excel using clipboard to Jquery grid and provide user an opportunity to edit the data copied and then save it to database.

Is there a way to do it with Jquery.

I am looking at Jquery grid examples

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In general, access to the cliboard is restricted by almost all browsers (to keep sites from stealing passwords which my be on the user's clipboard).  Unfortunately, there is no easy jQuery way of doing what you would like to do.

You will likely have to resort to a Adobe Flash plug-in to get the functionality you want. This applet works with most modern browsers and with Flash 10. Here is a good starting point for you: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/